# How to do nested groupby operations in a dataframe based on a condition on a column?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have to find the number of cycles within a column in my data frame (A cycle is defined when the variable goes from initial to some max value and again starts from some initial value). Whenever the variable has repeated values, I just average over them. In the desired data frame, I am appending the filter cycle number to that SNo as a suffix to know which cycle the given SNo is in. I need to get the min and the max for a given cycle and SNo (It is not predefined)

An example of the data frame and the desired data frame are as follows:

```
SNo  VarPer Value
1000    0   1.2
1000    1   2.2
1000    2   3.2
1000    3   4.2
1000    4   5.2
1000    4   6.2
1000    5   7.2
1000    5   8.2
1000    0   0.9
1000    1   1.9
1000    2   2.9
1000    3   3.9
1000    3   4.9
1000    4   5.9
1001    0   0.5
1001    1   1.5
1001    2   2.5
1001    2   3.5
1001    0   1
1001    1   1
1001    2   1
```

```
SNo   VarPer Value
1000_1  0   1.2
1000_1  1   2.2
1000_1  2   3.2
1000_1  3   4.2
1000_1  4   5.7
1000_1  5   7.7
1000_2  0   0.9
1000_2  1   1.9
1000_2  2   2.9
1000_2  3   4.4
1000_2  4   5.9
1001_1  0   0.5
1001_1  1   1.5
1001_1  2   3
1001_2  0   1
1001_2  1   1
1001_2  2   1
```

I have already tried the following:

```
y = dat.groupby(['SNo','VarPer'], as_index=False)['Value'].mean()
```

But this is grouping the entire thing without considering the cycles. I have about 70000 rows of data, so I need something that isn't terribly slow. Please help!

Comment: I think more information is needed. Exactly why do the first 6 rows all get `_1`, but the rows after that get `_2`, `_3`, etc., before restarting with a run of three `_1`s? How does the logic depend on the `VarPer` and/or `Value` columns`? How are you getting the max and initial values of the cycle - from the column, or predefined?

Comment: I made edits to the question. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Peter Leimbigler noted, I'm also not clear about the logic for how the suffix is generated. I would think 1000_3 through 1000_6 should all be 1000_2.

To use a groupby, you will need to create a new grouping with something like this:

```
for _, values in df.groupby('SNo'):
    group_label = 0
    for row in values.index:
        if df.loc[row, 'VarPer'] !=0:
            df.loc[row, 'group'] = group_label
        else:
            group_label+=1
            df.loc[row, 'group'] = group_label
```

EDIT: You probably shouldn't use a loop for writing directly to the dataframe. Instead, you can create a list and then create a new column using that list. This will be faster.

```
new_grouping = []
for _, values in df.groupby('SNo'):
    label = 0
    group = []
    for row in values.index:
        if df.loc[row, 'VarPer'] !=0:
            group.append(label)
        else:
            label+=1
            group.append(label)
    new_grouping.extend(group)
df['group'] = new_grouping
```

That won't be fast but perhaps you (or someone else) can vectorize it. 
Then you can use a groupby to get your averaged values:

```
df = df.groupby(['SNo','group'],as_index = False])["VarPer"].mean().reset_index()
```

If your suffixes are actually supposed to be as I describe above, you can do:

```
df['SNo'] = df['SNo'].map(str) +'_' + df['group'].map(lambda x: str(int(x)).zfill(2))
```

This will give you:

```
SNo  group VarPer Value
1000_1  1.0 0   1.2
1000_1  1.0 1   2.2
1000_1  1.0 2   3.2
1000_1  1.0 3   4.2
1000_1  1.0 4   5.7
1000_1  1.0 5   7.7
1000_2  2.0 0   0.9
1000_2  2.0 1   1.9
1000_2  2.0 2   2.9
1000_2  2.0 3   4.4
1000_2  2.0 4   5.9
1001_1  1.0 0   0.5
1001_1  1.0 1   1.5
1001_1  1.0 2   3.0
1001_2  2.0 0   1.0
1001_2  2.0 1   1.0
1001_2  2.0 2   1.0
```

Comment: You were right. I made the edits to the question. But I'm still not getting the same group number for all the values in the group

Comment: Were you not able to reproduce my results with the sample data you provided? Or does the problem only show up with the full data set?

Comment: ```df = df.groupby(['SNo','group'],as_index = False)["VarPer"].mean().reset_index()``` I made these changes and it worked perfectly then. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to vectorize this method as it is incredibly slow for a dataset containing ~77000 rows but been unsuccessful so far. Can someone give me pointers on how to optimize my code?

Comment: Please see edit--this should be faster and better because it doesn't write to df in the loop.

Comment: This approach has increased the speed almost 100x but the label logic got messed up. My current SNo's are like this: [1000_1,1000_2,1000_11,1000_12.....]

Comment: In the edit, we are assigning the group based on a grouped data frame but later we are adding it as a column to the original df(not the grouped one) which is messing up the order of the group column. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: The loop loops through the groups in the groupby and since we are not using an aggregate function, we are working with all the rows of that group. Take a look at, for example `df.groupby('SNo').get_group(1000)`. The logic is working on all of the rows so it will return a list the same length as your dataframe--it won't let you add it as a column if it's a different length. Regarding the order, are the labels incorrect or are they just out of order? We can add zero padding to the suffix if it's sorting incorrectly--see edit to last line.

Comment: Output for ```print(list(df['SNo'].unique()))``` is ['1000_01', '1000_02', '1000_03', '1000_12', '1000_13']. That means that the labels are incorrect right?

Comment: Does groupby change the order of the rows? My data is pretty sequential, so there is no need for the function to actually arrange it

Comment: Yeah, the labels are definitely incorrect if there's nothing between 1000_03 and 1000_12 but I can't reproduce with the sample you provided. The new group column also says 12 when SNo is 1000_12?

Comment: Yes, the new group column also says 12 when SNo is 1000_12. I'm seeing if I can convert the groupby object to a data frame so that I can append the new_grouping as a column to the "grouped-by-IMEI dataframe"